What are the oldest manuscripts of the Nevi'im books and specifically Melakhim?
I am especially interested in the oldest version of Melakhim/Kings, including any fragmentary sources like incomplete manuscripts in the dead sea scrolls.

Qumran manuscripts of Kings (4Q54, 5Q2 and 6Q4) consist of a few fragments and are dated to the late 2nd c. BCE - middle of the 1st c. BCE.
